# Wondering about tetrasilicates

Tags: ionic-compounds, structural-formula

I found two papers from which two different formulae for the tetrasilicate (tetrasilicic acid) are found:

1.https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022309302015491.
2.https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26482329.

Of course, the usual formula for polymerization of oxacids suggest the first one is the right one, that is, the tetrasilicate anion being $\ce,{Si_4O_9^{2-}}$, however, how to understand the second formula? Is something missing?

Comment: First you mention is cyclic, second linear, probably tetracyclic "tetrahedron of tetrahedra" also exists.

Comment: Yeah, but why? I believed the polymerized oxacid tetrasilicic acid had only a single formula...

Comment: "tetrasilicic acid" in not a  unique name. SiO4 tetrahedra may be connected in as many ways as possible.

Comment: Polymerization: n(oxoacid)-(n-1)$$H_2O$$. That is why I got surprised...

Comment: Just read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon%E2%80%93oxygen_tetrahedron

Comment: Polycondensation like this occurs for **di**functional monomers. Orthosilicic acid has **four** hydroxyl groups.

Comment: Without images this is unclear. Some people are actually sitting behind paywalls. Please [edit] your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Tetrasilicate" is one of special guys. For example, sulfate is $\ce{SO_4^2-}$, while $\ce{SO_3^2-}$ is sulfite. But tetrasilicate is $\ce{Si_4O_n^{(2n-16)-}}$ - thus, it simply has four $\ce{Si}$ atoms (without connotation that they have special number of oxygens near 'em): check for

http://www.biomedsearch.com/nih/Novel-silicate-anion-Si8O2212-Hydrothermal/11487344.html, which is also tetrasilicate (here tetrasilicate is $\ce{Si_4O_11^6-}$).

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/50934696_Preparation_structural_and_luminescent_properties_of_Ba2Gd2Si4O13Eu3_for_white_LEDs (tetrasilicate is $\ce{Si_4O_13^10-}$), etc.

[edited] I've found for you even tetrasilicate with 15 oxygens: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00710-016-0447-1

Also check for ***amicite*** (zeolite): it has approximation $\ce{K2Na2Al4Si4O16·5(H2O)}$. It seems for me like 16 oxygens is maximum for tetrasilicates, but maybe someone would disagree - interesting to know that other tetrasilicates exist.

Comment: How many special "guys" similar to tetrasilicates are out there? Wonderful!

Comment: Pretty many.$\,$

Comment: Examples out there?